# React native project - git commit triggers lint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json

The project which was created using react native worked fine and nothing much has been changed. I also updated to latest npm/node etc. but whenever I try to commit with git using command `git commit -am "test commit"` I get triggered the lint of react native and which says in the end:
[image]

The package.json which I have is:
https://hastebin.com/nadohasayi.json

It worked fine and now in the middle of the project the git issues could be critical.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: it looks like you have defined a *pre-commit* hook in your package.json

Comment: @QoP you are right, I noticed it now. Should I just remove it or what should be done?

Comment: You either remove it or you fix the lint errors :P

Comment: @QoP please put it as an answer and I will tag it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome buddy :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either remove the git hook in your `package.json` or you fix the lint errors.